# PHP MySQL results return double the values

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a page that returns some results from a SQL query to a MysQL database. For some reason, it's returning every value twice, I think because it's stored in the database both wth a numerical index, and a string index. How can I extract just the indexes and values that have a string index, and disregard those with a integer index?

The function I'm using to generate the table is below:

```
function SQLtable($answer) {
$result = "<table class=\"SQLresult\">";

$row = mysql_fetch_array($answer);

//TODO check for empty table here and return a message if empty

$result .= "<tr>";
foreach (array_keys($row) AS $heading) {
$result .= "<th>$heading</th>";
}
$result .= "</tr>";

do {
$result .= "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $cell) {
    $result .= "<td>".$cell."</td>";
    }
$result .= "</tr>";

}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($answer));

$result .= "</table>";
return $result;
}
```

A screenshot of the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YXoh.png

Thanks.

***edit1*** - The SQL I'm using is somewhat of a placeholder for testing. It is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM politicians";
```

I've also tried exlicitly asking for the columns, and I get the same problem.

```
$query = "SELECT firstname,lastname,jurisdiction,party,riding FROM politicians";
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL you are using to retrieve the data from your table. That is most likely what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_Fetch_array) will by default return a hash that contains both an associative array and a regular numeric-keyed result set of your row. To fetch one or the other use `mysql_fetch_row()` (array) or `mysql_fetch_assoc()` (hash), or specify what type you want using the optional second argument to `mysql_fetch_array()` as explained in its man page (linked above).

These are the equivalances:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($result) -> mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
mysql_fetch_row($result) -> mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
mysql_fetch_array($result) -> mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
```